# Un block delete method in nginx

Tags: nginx, configuration

When I tried to use delete method on nginx I get 403 access denied

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY BGCOLOR="white" FGCOLOR="black">
        <H1>Access Denied</H1>
        <HR>
            <FONT FACE="Helvetica,Arial">
                <B>
                  Description: You are not allowed to access the document you requested.
                </B>
            </FONT>
        <HR>
    </BODY>
```

I have searched configuration for any default block for delete method, but I can't find. I want to enable delete method in nginx, how can I do this?

**UPDATE:**

I don't log entry for delete alone but I can see for remaining all(get,post,patch,copy,head,unlink,put,options,link).

Comment: Could you please post the solution if you found one?